# Algorithm for optimizing computation of an arithmetic expression

Tags: algorithm, optimization, expression

Suppose I have an expression formed by integer variables and arithmetic operations: addition, subtraction and multiplication. I know that each multiplication takes M seconds, and each addition/substraction takes A seconds. Is there an algorithm which will compute the expression in the most efficient way for an arbitrary assignment to the variables? (Assume I can store in memory only one number).

Example:

M=10

A=1

Expression: a*a+a*b+b*b.

Initially, it has 3 multiplications and 2 additions, so the total time is 3*M+2*A=32

However, we can build an equivalent expression (a+b)*(a+b)-a*b which has only 2 multiplications and 3 additions, so the total computation time will be 2*M+3*A=23.

Comment: Do we have to take into account each M and A used in calculating the solution? ;)

Comment: Yes, each multiplication cost is M, and each addition costs. You cannot reuse the results you get. (Assume you are using reverse polish notation and calculating each + or * step by step).

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my question -- for example, in your example you describe the total computation time as `2*M+3*A=23`. I'm asking what about the M and A used in calculating your solution of `2*M+3*A=23`. Perhaps it takes another 3*M and 15*A to calculate the solution of 23. In that case the total would be 23+45...

Comment: No, we do not need to take into account the time(23) computation, assume we have a timer to measure it. 23 is the time we need to compute  a*a+a*b+b*b for arbitrary (integer) assignment to a and b, using the equivalent form (a+b)*(a+b)-a*b. I'm wondering if there is an algorithm(which can be arbitrary complex) to come up with an equivalent form which will lead to the fastest computation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to apply the sum product algorithm.

See:

http://www.isiweb.ee.ethz.ch/papers/docu/aloe-2001-1.pdf

Comment: I think it is not applicable here. First, it is used for computing marginals over product of factors, not variables. Second, it does not guarantee optimality in terms of number of operations  and depends on variable ordering you selected. If I'm wrong, could you show how to use it for the example I provided above?

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to reduce the number of multiplications. One approach is the following (i don't know whether the resulting cost reduction shall justify the algorithm complexity and cost):

1. Perfom addition on all operands for which addition is allowed as per operator precedence.
2. Form pairs of operands that have to undergo multiplication.
3. Among the pairs, take out the common operands and add their counterparts together.
4. Update the pairs and goto step 3.
5. Stop when no such common pairs are left. Then just do the remaining calculation.

   Ex:
   a*b + a*c + d*(e+f)
   perform addition on e & f (say g = e + f)
   a*b + a*c + d*g
   pairs: (a,b) (a,c) (d,g)
   a is common in the 1st two pairs so we add b & c.

Comment: That was my first idea. I cannot prove though that it always produces optimal result. How do you know that we will not need to add something to our original expression? For example , given some expression E we can add a*b to it, compute E+a*b (with possible simplifications) and substract a*b after that to get the original result?This leads to an infinite space of possible actions. How to prove that it is always more efficient to combine some products than to add something new to the expression?